# How to execute same test case multiple times in testlink configuration vice

Tags: testlink

We have approximate 7 different configurations to test same test case present in test link. But we can Fail/Pass a test case once only in testlink.

Configuration like:-

- Mac OS - Safari Window 10
- IE, edge, Chrome Window 7
- IE, edge, Chrome

**Along with different resolutions**

Now suppose my one testcase fail for mac safari but passing for IE then how I can execute the same testcase differently as per their configuration

Is there any solution for same so **we can execute the same testcase multiple times with-in the same build**, the only difference will be the configuration. I think may be using custom field but how?

My manager asked me to create different builds for all 7 configurations, Yes means 7 different build for each configuration  for the same test plan which is not looking a good approach to me.

**Any help would be appreciated**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestLink has a feature called Platform and that can be used achieve your requirement.
First, you need to create required Platforms(TestProject--Platform Management) Ex. Mac OS - Safari Window 10
[image: Add Platform]
Then Add those Platforms to the TestPlan( Test Plan Contents --Add/Remove Platforms)[image: Add to Plan]
Then select which Testcases need to run on which platform ( Test Plan Contents --Add/Remove Test Cases)
[image: Select TestCases]
Now Execute the Test Plan,  It will show the Test Plan, Platform, Build to select and execute the Testcase
[image: Execute Test]
Finally in reports( Test Result matrix) will show the TestCase Pass/ fail status under each platform.
[image: TestCase Status]

Comment: Thanks alot ... You saved me guy .. I can only give you bounty after 2 day

Comment: Happy to know my answer helped you.

Comment: Hi @Asanka .. I have started one bounty for a question related to testlink. please look into it if you have any answer related same :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041511/test-case-execution-in-testlink-with-testcase-unique-custom-field-by-uploading-x