# Test case execution in testlink with Testcase Unique custom field by uploading xml file

Tags: testlink

We are using Testlink 1.9.5. I want to execute my testcase using XML file.

**But I am facing one issue. my testcases is executing successfully but the custom field result(Actual Time custom field) is not saving. it's like testlink skip it**

I am using below XML :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>

  <testcase external_id="kan-8" >
    <tester>shubham</tester>
    <result>f</result>
    <notes> Test case has been passed scuccessfully </notes>
    <custom_fields>
     <custom_field>
        <name><![CDATA[Actual Time]]></name>
        <value><![CDATA[30]]></value>
    </custom_field>
  </custom_fields>
  </testcase>
</results>
```

I have tried with multiple permutation combeniation but every time I am getting a same result.

[image]

My custom fields are define as below :-

[image]